# Why am I getting some undefined items instead of sorted array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function bubble(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {

      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = arr[temp];
      }
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(bubble([5, 12, 2, 4, 10]));
```

My output is

```
[2, undefined, undefined, 4, 10]
```

I do not know why I am getting `undefined` instead of sorted array. I looked into some other code as well but did not work out.

Comment: Please show us some more code.

Comment: I assume this is for a test or project and you are not allowed to use `sort()`

Comment: You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take `temp` for swapping. See comment.

```js
function bubble(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {

      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp; // take just temp
      }
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(bubble([5, 12, 2, 4, 10]));
```